# Getting automatic results Using the .NET 4 Task Library

Tags: .net, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

Using the .NET 4 Task Library is there a way to automatically get notified of the results and keep track of the results without the usage of callbacks?

I am trying to create and start tasks asynchronously and get notified results automatically is there a way to do this with the .NET 4 Task Library?

Comment: The callback *is* your way of getting notified.

Comment: @Ek0nomik Is the callback the only way of getting notified, is there any updated method?

Comment: Perhaps you should explain what the problem of using callbacks is?  And what you mean by "automatically"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to create and start tasks asynchronously and get notified results automatically is there a way to do this with the .NET 4 Task Library?

With the `Task` class, you can schedule a *continuation* on the task.  Note that this is effectively still a form of callback, but it's created with a potentially nicer API:

```
Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew( () => SomeCodeAsync() );

task.ContinueWith( t =>
{
    // Run this after the task completes
}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Adding `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` in the continuation is completely optional.  If you're writing a GUI application, this will marshal the continuation back onto the initial synchronization context, which means you can access UI elements within that code directly without using another marshaling technique (such as `Dispatcher.Invoke`).

For more details, I'd suggest reading my [post on task continuations](http://reedcopsey.com/2010/04/19/parallelism-in-net-part-17-think-continuations-not-callbacks/) which goes into this in detail.